# How to use EF Core 5 to join and map tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm a beginner and trying to make many to many relationships between two classes with one relation ship class. But I got no result. How can I solve the issue?

I have used the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062468/how-to-change-foreign-key-name-in-ef-core-fluent-api) and the Example from EF core [documentation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx) as a basis, but without success.

table design:

[Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTheS.png)

[Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrpT.png)

with FK for UserID and RoleID
[UserRoles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHBxu.png)

code:

```
public class User
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> Roles { get; set; }
    }

public class Role
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRoles
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public string RoleID { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent API:

```
    public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entity)
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.ID);

            entity.HasMany(user => user.Roles)
                .WithOne(role => role.User)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID);
        }
    }

 public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> entity)
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.ID);

            entity.HasMany(role => role.Users)
                .WithOne(user => user.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleID);
        }
    }

 public class IdentifyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public IdentifyDBContext(DbContextOptions<IdentifyDBContext> options)
          : base(options)
        {
        }

      
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
  }
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks and best regards
fs

Comment: What does your migration look like?

Comment: I create the migfration

Comment: I have create the migration through the below code in the Program.CS. With the result, that the table __EFMigrationsHistory on the MSSQL-server was created with no entries. Thus, I assume that no migration is necessary. correct?
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdentifyDBContext>();
                db.Database.Migrate();
            }
 host.Run();
        }

Comment: You need to run the Add-Migration command in the nuget command line and pass a name like Add-Migration init.